# Trouble with variable. [Python]

Tags: python, windows

I have this variable on the beginning of the code:

```
enterActive = False
```

and then, in the end of it, I have this part:

```
def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.KeyID == 113: # F2
        doLogin()
        enterActive = True
    if event.KeyID == 13:  # ENTER     
        if enterActive == True:
            m_lclick()        
    return True

hookManager.KeyDown = onKeyboardEvent
hookManager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

and I get this error when I press enter first, and when I press F2 first:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'enterActive' referenced before assignment
```

I know why this happens, but I don't know how can I solve it...

anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Global variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/global-variables-in-python). Inside `onKeyboardEvent`, `enterActive` currently refers to a local variable, not the (global) variable you have defined outside the function. You need to put

```
global enterActive
```

at the beginning of the function to make `enterActive` refer to the global variable.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1**: Use a local variable.

```
def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    enterActive = false
    ...
```

**Approach 2**: Explicitly declare that you are using the global variable `enterActive`.

```
def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    global enterActive
    ...
```

Because you have the line `enterActive = True` within the function`onKeyboardEvent`, any reference to `enterActive` within the function uses the local variable by default, not the global one.  In your case, the local variable is not defined at the time of its use, hence the error.

Comment: You can use global variables without the global statement unless you want to declare them inside a local scope.

For python 2 at least.

Comment: You can in Python 3 too.  But the OP *is* declaring `enterActive = True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
enterActive = False

def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    global enterActive
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the answer:

[Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/global-variables-in-python)

You are writing to a global variable and have to state that you know
what you're doing by adding a "global enterActive" in the beginning of
your function:

```
def onKeyboardEvent(event):
    global enterActive
    if event.KeyID == 113: # F2
        doLogin()
        enterActive = True
    if event.KeyID == 13:  # ENTER     
        if enterActive == True:
            m_lclick()        
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to declare enterActive in another function and you aren't using the global statement to make it global. Anywhere in a function where you declare the variable, add:

```
global enterActive
```

That will declare it as global inside the functions.